# Firebase retrieve user number to web

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Hello I am building a small dashboard for my app. I am a bit new with Firebase but it saves me a lot of time. So what I wanted to do is to retrieve the number of total registred users from the database stright to the web dashboard or any other relavant data later in the future. So what I did not is made a small login form and I can login. Maybe someone has any similar experience I have added the structure of my database in the picture.

```
    // Initialize Firebase
var config = {
  apiKey: "...",
      authDomain: "...",
      databaseURL: "...",
      storageBucket: "...",
  messagingSenderId: "..."
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

// Firebase Variables
var auth = firebase.auth();

// on state changed
auth.onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => {
  // check email
  if(firebaseUser){

    currentEmail.innerHTML = auth.currentUser.email
    currentEmail.style.display = 'block';
    singoutButton.style.display = 'block';
    //singupForm.style.display = 'none';
    signin.style.display = 'none';
    signinEmail.style.display = 'none';
    signinPassword.style.display = 'none';
    signintext.style.display = 'none';
    welcometext.style.display = 'block';
    window.location = 'index.html';
  } else{
    signintext.style.display = 'block';
    welcometext.style.display = 'none';
    signin.style.display = 'block';
    signinEmail.style.display = 'block';
    signinPassword.style.display = 'block';
    singoutButton.style.display = 'none';
    //singupForm.style.display = 'block';
    currentEmail.style.display = 'none';
  }

});
```

[Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QJsI.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve the number of users, try the following:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("users");
ref.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
var numberOfChildren = snapshot.numChildren();
});
```

Assuming `users` is a direct child to the root node.

> `numChildren()` returns number
>
> Returns the number of child properties of this DataSnapshot.

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#numChildren

Comment: Thanks a lot I used as use said and added console.log(snapshot.numChildren()); after it shows in the console the exact number of users. How could I append the result to the HTML?